# OpenGL: Current raster position stays invalid (freaky error, makes no sense)

Tags: opengl

I am getting a rather odd error while displaying bitmap texts on screen and using glRasterPos3f function to position them. When I start the application, all my texts fit inside the view and everything works fine and dandy. However, things start to get really messed up as soon as one of them gets outside the view - all my texts disappear and won't reappear ever again not even if I set the view back to its original position.

I did some investigation and made an explicit check of the raster position validity flag, like this:

```
glRasterPos3f(xPos, yPos, zPos);

// check raster position validity
GLboolean valid;
pin_ptr<GLboolean> p_valid = &valid;
glGetBooleanv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION_VALID, p_valid);
if (!valid)
  return;
```

Well now this is when things start to really boggle my mind - the condition at the end of this code gets triggered not just when a text position gets outside the view, but from then on ever since! It drives me into despair. Even if I restore the view to its usual working state, the validity bit appears to stay cleared forever. Any ideas on what might be the possible cause for this or maybe how to restore raster position manually somehow?

EDIT: Some pics...

Initial state, all is well:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKl2k.png

I zoom in, some raster position gets invalid, texts disappear:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgQI9.png

When I zoom back out again, there still aren't any texts...

Comment: When you say you restore the view to its usual working state... do you mean, you set the raster pos to a point that is not clipped? The _current raster position_ becomes undefined when it is set to a clipped location and remains that way until the next time you call `glRasterPos<N>f (...)` with a valid position.

Comment: Well, that is what I thought too, but in my case, the position remains undefined even if I call that again with a valid position.

Answer (score 3):

All OpenGL raster operations are discarded if the glRasterPos transforms to outside the clip space to NDC space volume. So if your text starts out at a position outside the visible viewport it won't show up. And if the text extends to beyond the visible viewport, everything after the last character visible will get messed up.

Which means, glRasterPos is rather useless. It's use is strongly discouraged, as are all OpenGL raster operations. In fact those have been removed entirely from modern OpenGL versions.

Comment: Sure, but in my case, it doesn't really matter if the text won't show up if only a small part of it is outside the viewport. Making all other texts disappear is however a different story (and a rather sad one indeed).

Comment: @MartinZáleta: My suggestion is: Don't use raster operations. They're cumbersome to work with and simply not worth the effort. Use FreeType to rasterize the text you want to display into an image, load that image into texture and draw that on a quad. If you can limit yourself to a small set of characters (e.g. the latin alphabet), then using texture mapped fonts would work as well.

Comment: But would such approach lead to scale-invariant texts as well?

Comment: @MartinZáleta: Of course. OpenGL projections can be changed anytime, anyhow you want to. Just switch to a pixel mapping projection for text drawing operations and draw the quads in pixel units.

Comment: Do you have some source (link) on how to set the projection to work like that?

Comment: @MartinZáleta: `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); glOrtho(0, viewport_width, 0, viewport_height, -1, 1); glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity();` or the equivalent in a programmable pipeline. Remember: OpenGL is a state driven drawing API. You may change the state whenever to whatever you require at the moment. If it's drawing in pixel units you can set that.

Comment: @MartinZáleta: Of course, if you made the newbie/bad tutorial mistake of setting viewport and projection in some window resize handler, instead of in the drawing/display function (where it belongs), then it might not be the obvious thing to do.

Comment: Yes, but this approach seems to lead towards rendering stuff as if it was an overlay or HUD, but I still need to have those texts "pinned" somewhere in 3D space. So, this way I still need to trasform their position from model coords to window coords myself, right?

Comment: @MartinZáleta: Doing the transformation yourself is indeed required, but not that hard. Also it's perfectly possible to render the text as a screen aligned billboard; this still requires the scale be adjusted by the depth, but that can be done using a vertex shader, that receives the anchor point as a uniform.

Comment: Okay, I pretty much understand so far, but how do I adjust the scale by the depth - what relation is there between those two?

Comment: @MartinZáleta: `s = k*d`, where `d` is the distance to the plane of point of view and `k = tan(field of view)/near`. However if you substitute those terms in the actual vertex shader to generate the billboard you'll notice that most of the terms cancel out with the elements of the modelview matrix very nicely.